# Where can I access mono-develop on Ubuntu 10.10 ? I'm done installing it using synaptic manager

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I just browsed for mono-devel on the synaptic manager and installed it with its dependencies. Now, I'm stocked. I don't know if I still need to configure something, run some scripts on a terminal. I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ubuntu software center to install monodevelop IDE then it will appear on applications->programming.